# What is the derivation of “skinny malink”?

Tags: etymology

But despite my wife’s insistence, everyone knows it is more properly *skinny merrink*. I don’t care what Oxford English says!

*Oxford Dictionaries Online* offers the following for *[skinnymalinky](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/skinnymalinky)* (and nothing for *merrink*)

> (plural skinnymalinkies)
>
> *Scottish* A very thin person: *that young skinnymalinks above the shop*

It goes on to note

> **Origin:** Late 19th century: origin uncertain; a Scottish children's song related the adventures of a thin man known as ‘Skinamalinky Long Leg’.

A version of the lyrics is found at the *[Online Dictionary of Playground Slang](http://www.odps.org/glossword/index.php?a=term&d=3&t=209)*

> Skinny Malinky lang legs, umbrella feet
>
> Went to the pictures (cinema) and couldnae find a seat
>
> When the picture (film) started
>
> Skinny Malinky farted
>
> When the picture ended
>
> Skinny Malinky fented (fainted)

However there is no indication of the derivation of the term *malinky* or *malink*.

Numerous references are found at *[wordwizard.com](http://www.wordwizard.com/phpbb3/viewtopic.php?t=17996)* dating back to 1892, but again, no indication of the origin of the term *malink*.

There are a variety of spellings, including *melink, balink* and most importantly, *marink* or *merink* (with single or double *r*s) the form from my childhood.

Can anyone help with the source of *malink* (or even better, *merrink*)?

Comment: I knew it. Scots are weirdos.

Comment: Well in Ireland we have skinny malinkys not merrinks.

Comment: @DanBron No we arny :p

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The original and older spelling appears to be "skinnymalink". The following  extract from the [The New York Times](http://www.nytimes.com/1994/07/10/magazine/on-langauge-now-overhear-this.html) suggests that  in this case the image of skinniness may have been derived from the that of a chain and hooks (links) that hold a pot over the fire:

> - From skinny malink, ***in a comic song on the London stage around 1870.***  The Scottish National Dictionary has skinnymalink(ie), for an emaciated person or animal.
> - ***Joan Hall of the Dictionary of American Regional English, thinks it is rooted in skinny as the links of a crook***, the chain and hook that hold a pot over a fire.
> - "***The ma- is probably an infix," she tells me, "a rhythmic syllable added to make the phrase more euphonious."***
> - In 1924, Eddie Cantor popularized the song "Skin-a-Ma-Rink," written by Al Dubin, Jimmy McHugh and Irving Mills.

As noted by the [Phrase Finder](http://www.phrases.org.uk/bulletin_board/21/messages/1123.html):

> - ***Thin people inspire almost as many names and jokes as fat people,*** but the laughter is less mortifying; the names cannot insinuate self-indulgence, they are merely descriptive, as, bag o' bones, bean pole, Bony Moroney (Glasgow)......skinny-flint or skinflint (curiously common in this sense),skinny guts, Skinny Liz, skinny-malink, spaggy oe sparrow.......

Comment: +1 for great info and reminding me how much I miss Safire.

Answer (score -2):

Possibly a Russian connection as "malink" more or less means the little one?

Comment: So now Russians are interfering in Scottish language development?

Comment: @MetaEd [Oh, those Russians!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6jxqn-HOiR8)